# Does special relativity happen in reverse when you freeze?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, observers

As you travel faster and faster you experience time at a slower rate, so if you travel slower and slower you should experience it at a faster rate right?

My thinking is that even if you are stationary, your atoms are still moving so if you slowed and stopped them from moving by removing energy from them (freezing them), would time appear to go slower? or does this situation not apply to special relativity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You experience time normally always. You'll never notice that the world around you looks slow, or some such thing. What special relativity says is that other observers, observing a clock that is moving relative to them, will see that clock as moving slowly. You are never moving with respect to yourself, of course, so you always see "ordinary" time.

Basically, the reduction of special relativity to "if I travel faster, time moves slower for me" is a little disingenuous, because you have to ask "slower than who?" And from your perspective, the clock moves normally, and everyone else's clock moves slowly.

Answer (score 0):

What matters for calculating time dilation is the size of your velocity, not its direction.

Meaning, traveling in a certain direction with velocity v, traveling in the opposite direction with the same velocity, or traveling in some arbitrary direction with this velocity, all cause the same time dilation.

This should be evident, because no direction in space is different from any other. (i.e., space has no special orientation)

For the time dilation factor, see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor